# Load Xcode snippets with restarting the Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, plugins, xcode5, code-snippets

I am creating a plugin for Xcode. Which would download code snippets from remote location 
and drop into Xcode user snippets folder. which is

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets
```

Every thing is working fine except that I need to restart the Xcode every time I download code snippets.I want to load newly added code snippets without restarting Xcode.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a similar plugin to synchronize snippets with a git repository. You can check the source code here: https://github.com/acoomans/ACCodeSnippetRepositoryPlugin.

Having the snippet library update when snippets change (both way) isn't trivial and required [swizzling](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html) XCode' internals classes.

Xcode has a *IDECodeSnippetRepository* class responsible of saving snippets on disk when created or edited, and deleting them when removed.

ACCodeSnippetRepositoryPlugin has a *IDECodeSnippetRepositorySwizzler* class that swizzle the *saveUserCodeSnippetToDisk:* and *removeCodeSnippet:* methods with custom implementations of my own, syncing the snippet with the git repo.

[image]

Actually, to be really precise, my IDECodeSnippetRepositorySwizzler can have multiple code snippet *data stores* attached and will call the *addCodeSnippet:* and *removeCodeSnippet:* methods on each of them when the create/edit/delete events happen.

ACCodeSnippetRepositoryPlugin was intended to be able to manage multiple snippets sources (like git, gist, etc...) but I didn't finished implementing it.
I giving this precision because, I don't know with what you want to synchronize your snippets, but I may make sense to add your functionality to ACCodeSnippetRepositoryPlugin.